# Keras Model Training with Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, keras

I have trained a multiclass-classification model locally using Keras. I am attempting to migrate this so that it can be trained and run in Azure Machine Learning Studio (AML).

I have provided the sections of code below which are used in AML - the *Main AML Code* and the script to train the model (*EnsemblingModel.py)*. From the Main AML Code, the script to train the model is called via src = (Script Run Config).

Please note that I have also uploaded the dataset which the model should be trained upon to AML directly and is titled **'test_data'**.

However an error is returned when executing the line **RunDetails(run).show()** from the *Main AML code* section. The error is:

```
Error occurred: User program failed with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_data'
```

This error message refers to the the following line from the **EnsemblingModel.py** script:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("test_data", header=None)
```

I understand that the script is unable to load the data and I have therefore tried changing the code, for example:

```
dataframe = dataset.get_by_name(ws, name='test_data')
```

Which returned the following error:

```
Error occurred: User program failed with NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined
```

How do I change this so that the script is able to read and load the data so that training can commence? Maybe I am going about this completely the wrong way, so any advice is welcomed.

I have consulted the various Microsoft documentation as well as Github azure guides [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/keras/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-keras/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-keras.ipynb), but there seems to be limited examples.

I am new to AML, so if anyone has any resources for using it alongside Keras, then that would also be appreciated.

Main AML Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import azureml
from azureml.core import Experiment
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import Dataset
from azureml.core import Workspace, Run
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute_target import ComputeTargetException

ws = Workspace.from_config()
print('Workspace name: ' + ws.name, 
      'Azure region: ' + ws.location, 
      'Subscription id: ' + ws.subscription_id, 
      'Resource group: ' + ws.resource_group, sep='\n')

from azureml.core import Experiment

script_folder = './TestingModel1'
os.makedirs(script_folder, exist_ok=True)

exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='TestingModel1')

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, name='test_data')
dataframe = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
df = dataframe.values


cluster_name = "cpu-cluster"

try:
    compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=cluster_name)
    print('Found existing compute target')
except ComputeTargetException:
    print('Creating a new compute target...')
    compute_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(vm_size='STANDARD_NC6',
                                                           max_nodes=4)

    compute_target = ComputeTarget.create(ws, cluster_name, compute_config)

    compute_target.wait_for_completion(show_output=True, min_node_count=None, timeout_in_minutes=20)

compute_targets = ws.compute_targets
for name, ct in compute_targets.items():
    print(name, ct.type, ct.provisioning_state)

from azureml.core import Environment

keras_env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name = 'keras-2.3.1', file_path = './conda_dependencies.yml')

# Specify a GPU base image
#keras_env.docker.enabled = True
keras_env.docker.base_image = 'mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.0-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04'

from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=script_folder,
                      script='EnsemblingModel.py',
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=keras_env)

run = exp.submit(src)

from azureml.widgets import RunDetails
RunDetails(run).show()
```

Ensembling Model Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#KerasLibraries
from keras import callbacks
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils

#tensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf

#SKLearnLibraries
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from azureml.core import Run

# In[3]:

dataframe = pd.read_csv("test_data", header=None)
dataframe = dataset.get_by_name(ws, name='test_data')
dataset = dataframe.values


# In[4]:


X = dataset[:,0:22].astype(float)
y = dataset[:,22]

# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)

print(dummy_y.shape)
#print(X.shape)
#print(X)
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
dummy_y_new = dummy_y[0:42,:]

print(dummy_y_new)
#dataset


# In[5]:


earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss", 
                                        mode ="min", patience = 125, 
                                        restore_best_weights = True)
  
#define Keras
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(50, input_dim=22))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5,input_shape=(50,)))
model1.add(Dense(50))
model1.add(BatchNormalization())
model1.add(Activation('relu'))
model1.add(Dropout(0.5,input_shape=(50,)))
model1.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

#compile the keras model

model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])   

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model1.fit(X, dummy_y, validation_split=0.25, epochs=10000, batch_size=100, verbose=1, callbacks=[earlystopping])


_, accuracy3 = model1.evaluate(X, dummy_y, verbose=0)

print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy3*100))

    
predict_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor([
            [1,5,1,0.459,0.322,0.041,0.002,0.103,0.032,0.041,14,0.404,0.284,0.052,0.008,0.128,0.044,0.037,0.043,54,0,155],
])


predictions = model1(predict_dataset, training=False)
   
predictions2 = predictions.numpy()
print(predictions2)
print(type(predictions2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the above issue by adding an argument to the ScriptRunConfig code:

```
test_data_ds = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, name='test_data')

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=script_folder,
                      script='EnsemblingModel.py',
                      # pass dataset as an input with friendly name 'titanic'
                      arguments=['--input-data', test_data_ds.as_named_input('test_data')],
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=keras_env)
```

As well as the following to the modelling script itself:

```
import argparse
from azureml.core import Dataset, Run

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input-data", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

run = Run.get_context()
ws = run.experiment.workspace

# get the input dataset by ID
dataset = Dataset.get_by_id(ws, id=args.input_data)

# load the TabularDataset to pandas DataFrame
df = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
dataset = df.values
```

For anyone curious, more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-datasets):